# (Android) API-specific styles?

Tags: java, android

For my Android app, I want my app to have translucent status and navigation bars on KitKat (API level 19).  How do I make it so level 19 API operating systems have transparent status/navigation bars, while non-KitKat ones to have normal bars.

Comment: use styles.xml definitions in values-v19 and values

Comment: @njzk2 May I ask how this is done?

Comment: @njzk2 The highest values I can find is values-v14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a custom theme, and set these properties for API level 19.

First, create a `styles.xml` file in `res\values`

It should have the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

The `parent="@android:style/Theme"` may be different according to the base theme you want (e.g. `Theme.Light`, `Theme.Holo`, `Theme.Holo.Light`, or whatever).

Then create a similar `styles.xml` file in `res\values-v19`, with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
       <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

(Same as before, parent may be different).

And in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, look for the `application` node, and add/update the theme attribute, i.e.

```
<application
    android:icon= ...
    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme">
```

Comment: I see 2 values folders: one in app/src/main/res and one in build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/res.  Which one do I use?

Comment: Always in `src`. The other folder is created by the build process, you should never touch anything inside it.

Comment: How do I "Configure it in AndroidManifest.xml"? What codes will I need?

Comment: If you already have a styles.xml in `values-v14` then skip all that first part. Just copy it into `values-v19` and add the two "item" lines under the style element.

Comment: Is values-v14 required or can I have an ordinary folder called values?

Comment: You can have as many as you like. From your comment in the question I assumed you already had values-v14?

Comment: Actually I have only a "Values" folder.  I have done what you said, and I'm getting the error: execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResource'.  I made a folder called values-v19, and named the XML file styles19.xml.  Do I need to do something with AndroidManifest?